# How to create a copy of items in database without breaking FK constraints?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Ok so I have a structure like this (don't know how to format this properly but I'll try):

- Table **Location**, contains `id, name` and `address`.
- Table **Room**, which contains `id, name, size` and a foreign key to a location.
- Table **RoomItem** (think tables, chairs etc), contains `id, name, type, value` and a foreign key to a room.

So let's say I have set up a location with a dozen rooms and a hundred roomitems using this structure. Now I want to create a new location, but I want to have exactly the same rooms and roomitems as a template for the new location. So basically I'd want to copy all rooms pointing to a certain location and change their FK to the new location, as well as copy all the roomitems pointing to said rooms, and change their FKs to point to the newly created rooms.

I am using Entity Framework 4.3, but anything executable from a standard c# winforms project would work just fine.

And my problem is figuring out how to do this "properly". Doing it all manually seems like quite the hassle, meaning something like going through the rooms one by one, copying all their fields and creating a new one, then diving deeper into its roomitems and copying them, after saving the first room so I have its id available.

Even writing this out sounds quite confusing, so is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide a way of doing this below, in SQL. Please note this answer is subject to the following caveats:

I am answering without having available any development tools, or reference material. This means that the answer comes out of my memory.

In particular this implies that the solution has not been compiled; also its syntax and semantics may be off in some respects.

I have used the variant of sql that I know best - that for Firebird. The exact syntax you need may vary depending on the sql that is available to you.

In addition I have assumed that the variable names are sufficiently self explanatory to warrant no further comment.

Finally, this answer can probably be improved - the repetition of SELECT statements indicates to me that there is a refinement that will remove this repetition.

```
SET TERM !! ;

CREATE TRIGGER Deep_Copy_Room FOR Location
BEFORE INSERT
POSITION 0

AS BEGIN

NEW.id = GEN_ID (id_GEN, 1);
INSERT INTO Room (id, name, size, fk) 
       VALUES (GEN_ID(id_GEN, 1), Roo_name, Roo_Size, NEW.id) 
       WHERE SELECT id, name, size, FK_id FROM Room AS Roo_Id, Roo_name, Roo_size
               WHERE SELECT id, name, addrss FROM Location AS Loc_Id, Loc_name, Loc_address
                       WHERE fk = Copy_From_id;
INSERT INTO Item (id, name, type, value, fk_id) 
       VALUES (GEN_ID(id_GEN,1), Ite_name, Ite_type, Ite_value, Roo_id)
       WHERE SELECT id, name, type, value, FK_id FROM RoomItem AS Ite_Id, Ite_name, Ite_type, Ite_value, Roo_Id)
               WHERE SELECT id, name, size, FK_id FROM Room AS Roo_Id, Roo_name, Roo_size, Loc_id
                       WHERE SELECT id, name, address FROM Location AS Loc_Id, Loc_name, Loc_address
                               WHERE Loc_id = Copy_From_id;

END

SET TERM ; !!
```

Comment: Thanks, so I guess the "manual" option is the only option in this case.